# how can i upload a small Mat to a bigger GpuMat in opencv

Tags: opencv, upload, gpu, mat

what can i do if i want to upload a small size MAt to a bigger GpuMat and fill  the other entries with a constant number ?? for example, if Mat has a 5*5 size and GpuMat has a 7*7 size ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROI access to `GpuMat`:

```
GpuMat bigmat(7, 7, CV_8UC1);
Mat smallmat(5, 5, CV_8UC1);
GpuMat roi = bigmat(Rect(1, 1, smallmat.cols, smallmat.rows)); // choose ROI for uploading
roi.upload(smallmat);
```